# Find symmetry in Array

Tags: c, arrays, function

Hi i need to check if the array is symmetry or not. i have a function that  takes in a two-dimensional array of integer numbers M and the array sizes for rows and columns as parameters, and returns 1 if M is symmetric or 0 otherwise. I tried many times but the output will be either yes to non-symmetric array or no to symmetric array

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
#define INIT_VALUE -1
int symmetry2D(int M[][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize);
int main()
{
    int M[SIZE][SIZE], i, j, result = INIT_VALUE;
    int rowSize, colSize;
    printf("Enter the array size (rowSize, colSize): \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &rowSize, &colSize);
    printf("Enter the matrix (%dx%d): \n", rowSize, colSize);
    for (i = 0; i < rowSize; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < colSize; j++)
            scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);
    result = symmetry2D(M, rowSize, colSize);
    if (result == 1)
        printf("symmetry2D(): No\n");
    else if (result == 0)
        printf("symmetry2D(): Yes\n");
    else
        printf("Error\n");
    return 0;
}

int symmetry2D(int M[][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    int h, k, temp;
    int result;

    for (h = 0; h < rowSize; h++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < colSize; k++)
        {
            M[h][k] = M[k][h];
        }

    }

    result = 0;
    for (h = 0; h < rowSize && result; h++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < colSize; k++)
        {
            //if it is not equal to its transpose
            if (M[h][k] != M[h][k])
            {
                result = 1;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    if (result == 0)
    {
        for (h = 0; h < rowSize; h++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < colSize; k++)
            {
                return result = 0;
            }

        }

    }
    else
        return result = 1;
}
```

Comment: Define symmetrical 2D array.

Comment: BTW, `result =0;
    for(h=0;h<rowSize && result; h++)` will never run.

Comment: still not working well @EugeneSh. i have added more code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Very good point. x/y axis symmetric? Diagonal symmetric? Which dimension is x/y? Is the array square?

Comment: they are symmetric iff it is equal to its transpose @DevNull

Comment: You seem to be saying that the program *always* returns the wrong answer, whether the input is symmetric or non-symmetric.  If that's true then it seems your code is working, but you are somewhere inverting the sense of the result.  Inverting it back should then solve the problem.

Comment: like for eg i keyed in a symmetric input, the result will be yes. And if i keyed non symmetric input, the result will still be yes... @JohnBollinger

Comment: I'd recommend a slightly different signature: `bool isSymmetric2D(/* as was.. */)` - need to `#include <stdbool.h>` for, though.

Comment: @DevNull Taking into account this assignment M[h][k] = M[k][h];
 it looks like he means main diagonal symmetric for a square two-dimensional array.:)

Comment: A little off-topic, but get used to check user input right from the start: `rowSize` and `colSize` must not exceed `SIZE` (using `unsigned int` makes checking for negative numbers obsolete...), and you cannot have a symmetry if numbers of rows and cols are not equal. After every call to scanf, you should check for fail bits being set (invalid user input such as "xyz" leads to!): [`ferror`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ferror)-function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Very true. I like like to encourage SO posters (especially new ones) to be very explicit with their intent. :)

Answer (score 2):

Several issues:

1. By your definition, a matrix is symmetric if and only if it is equal to its transpose.  That can be the case only for square matrices, yet you accommodate non-square matrices as well, for no apparent reason.
2. Your `symmetry2D()` function contains serious logical flaws:

   - It *makes* the input symmetric via the loop that performs `M[h][k] = M[k][h]`
   - Even if it did not do so, it would never find the input non-symmetric, because its test for that is `if (M[h][k] != M[h][k])`, which must always fail.
3. It's unclear what you think the `if`/`else` and loop nest at the end of `symmetry2D()` are achieving for you, but provided that `rowSize` and `colSize` are both greater than zero, the *actual* effect of the whole construct is the same as a simple `return result;`.

It looks like the idea might have been to create an array containing the transpose of the input, and then compare the input to that.  That would have worked, despite being rather grotesquely inefficient, but you never in fact create that separate array for the transpose.  If you're going to test without creating the transpose -- which you should -- then

1. Do not modify the input array (so remove the first loop nest altogether).
2. Get your indexing right for the symmetry comparisons: `M[h][k] != M[k][h]`
3. For best efficiency, avoid redundant and needless comparisons.  For example, if you have already tested the `M[1][2] == M[2][1]` then you do not need to test whether `M[2][1] == M[1][2]`.  And you never need to test elements on the main diagonal.  You could achieve this efficiency pretty easily with a better choice of loop bounds.

Also, if indeed the `symmetry2D()` function is supposed to avoid modifying the input array, consider declaring the element type for its first argument to be `const int` instead of plain `int` (but do not modify the type of the corresponding variable in `main()`).  If you had written it that way in the first place then the compiler would have noticed the function's logically erroneous attempt to modify the array elements, and rejected the code.